# Read, change and save doc in Javascript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to read file (.doc) then replace some data in doc and then send to print (doc or pdf).

At first step I try to read data from docs. From .txt its work, but from .doc no :(

I did example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qo0fxo50/

I try to do it like:

```
<h1>Select file</h1>
    <input type="file" on-read-file="showContent($fileContent)" />
    <div>
        <h2>File content is:</h2>
        <pre>{{ contentfile }}</pre>
    </div>
```

And directive (on-read-file):

```
directives.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

                element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {


                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.target).files[0], 'CP1251');
                    reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                        });
                    };


                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I did example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qo0fxo50/

Answer (score 3):

.doc is a proprietary and binary format (also there are multiple incompatible versions).
That means it's a bunch of undocumented bytes instead of some charackters as with .txt.

You won't get anything out of it unless you understand the details of that format or find a library that helps you to read it. I'd suggest automate '.doc-contents to something you can parse'-conversion with a tool (there should be something out there, but don't exspect accurate results) or even better don't use .doc.

As for the new .docx formats it should be a little easier to get contents, as they are basically .xml.