# PDF content display issue

Tags: angularjs

[Read, change and save doc in Javascript (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563539/read-change-and-save-doc-in-javascript-angular/53058092#53058092)

Above is the code for reading content of PDF.  When I upload a PDF,  the contests of PDF is displaying in unreadable format.

Comment: Yes it is duplicate question. But when I upload a PDF,  it is displaying unreadable contents.

Comment: Please update this to provide your own situation along with code.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a read as text, it applies a certain encoding (ASCII, Unicode etc) to the underlying binary 0/1 characters to do the reading. This is what causing the special characters. Hence you need to upload/download files as stream (not sure of AngularJS reference of how to do it). 
Please check this [AngularJS: how to implement a simple file upload with multipart form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963022/angularjs-how-to-implement-a-simple-file-upload-with-multipart-form)

Comment: My scenario is little different. I'm uploading a PDF and I'm not saving it anywhere. I'm just trying to read the content of uploaded PDF and saving the content in scope variable.

Comment: Post your entire code how and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This is the example I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/qo0fxo50/